# How to get "HTML Page" option inside add menu on right clicking solution in Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012

I wasted good amount of time researching on how to achieve this functionality. It might be a simple change in check box or installing an extension of some sort. But I just don't get how to do it.

Wanted Feature:
[image: VisualStudioFeatureToAddHTMLPage]

Current Feature:
[image]

I was following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ja2xDrtylBw) for learning AngularJS. And I am completely suffering to find a way to add blank html pages to current solution.

Steps followed to create the project: 
File -> New Project -> Installed/Templates/Visual C#/Web/ADP.NET MVC4 WEB APPLICATION -> Web API.

How do I get the simple shortcut in the Add box to add a HTML Page ??

Please throw in your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I did it. It's called an Item template. And Microsoft has a good documentation on how to create item templates [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx).